# Disable dates by name of day in jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can someone let me know if it's possible to disable dates in the datepicker by passing day names to it?

Eg.  I would like to only allow dates that fall on a Wednesday, Friday and Sunday and grey out all other dates.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `beforeShowDay` event of datepicker to disable days conditionally. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: filterDays
  });
});

// getDay() method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) where 
// Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on.
function filterDays(date) {
   var day = date.getDay();
   //return true only if day is Wed or Fri or Sun
   return (day == 3 || day == 5 || day == 0);
}
```